# Why dagger requires to provide entities where I don't want to provide them?

Tags: kotlin, dagger

I have two modules - `core` and `auth`. In auth module I am trying to integrate Google Sign In to Firebase. All dependencies resolving correctly, but not a GoogleSignInClient. I don't want use dagger for this entity to provide this client somewhere. I want to use it only in this class. But dagger shows me an error :

```
  class file for com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient not found
  Consult the following stack trace for details.
  com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient not found
e: D:\Projects\<project path>\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\internalProductionDebug\<class path>\di\components\AppComponent.java: error: 
[ComponentProcessor:MiscError] dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this interface because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
```

Comment: If you're sure to not require the client as a dependency, this might be an issue with some _Gradle_ and _Kapt_ caches.

Comment: Could you post code of dagger components? Please, check that `GoogleSignInClient` is not used in constructors, method parameters or fileds declaration marked with `@Inject` annotation.

Comment: @tynn do we have any workarounds for this case?

Comment: Sometimes it was sufficient to kill the _Gradle_ deamon. Once I removed everything related to _Gradle_ and _Android Studio_ from the computer. You'd have to figure out where and why it's used.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it wasn't dagger problem. It happens with using several Android modules when you use `api` and `implementation` in gradle incorrectly.

I don't know why, but when I fixed my dependencies in Gradle - all become working.